# Unable to get the value using getAttribute method,and Javascript in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, dom, functional-testing, data-driven

[the element marked i want to get the value to compare it with excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5kuc.png)

```
@FindBy(id="TAXEI")
//@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='TAXEI']")
public WebElement taxesEIvalue;


public void verifyTaxesEIvalue() {
    //jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('type', '')",taxesEIvalue);

String value=taxesEIvalue.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println("the value is "+value);
}
```

I am facing problem to get the value in an application to compare it from excel,but unable to get value through Dom structure.The Html structure did't provide Value attribute

Here is the html code for the element unable to get the value that is in text box,i have compare with that value with the excel data using data driven

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <fieldset class="fsStyle">
                        <legend class="legendStyle">
                            <label class="control-label main">TAXES</label>
                        </legend>
                        <div class="wages">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <label class="control-label">EI</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <input type="text" class="control-label TAX pull-right" id="TAXEI" disabled="disabled">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <label class="control-label">QPIP</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <input type="text" class="control-label TAX pull-right" id="TAXQPIP" disabled="disabled">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <label class="control-label">CPP</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <input type="text" class="control-label TAX pull-right" id="TAXCPP" disabled="disabled">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <label class="control-label">QPP</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <input type="text" class="control-label TAX pull-right" id="TAXQPP" disabled="disabled">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <label class="control-label">Income Tax</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <input type="text" class="control-label TAX pull-right" id="TAXIT" disabled="disabled">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <label class="control-label">Quebec Tax</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <input type="text" class="control-label TAX pull-right" id="TAXQTax" disabled="disabled">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a id="divExemptNamesIncome"></a>
                            <p class="form-control-static"><strong id="divExemptNamesIncome"></strong></p>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you share before and after 10 lines of HTML what you mentioned above?

Comment: hi  Sreenivasulu , i have added the html snippet check once and let me know any solution for this

Comment: Hi Phani, After reviewing HTML content, the xpath what you have written (//*[@id='TAXEI') matched element does not have any attribute with the name of "value". Hence, when you try to fetch information using "value", nothing will be returned. Also, When I click on "Run Code Snippet" from your query above, loaded page does not have any values like what you are expecting. Hence, the values what you expected are not part of this HTML code and it may be in different place

Comment: Can you check your HTML code once where you are able to see the values like '129.60' etc. Right click on this value from your application and check whether HTML is holding this value inside it. If it is, it is possible to do by using Selenium. Can you check and confirm once?

Comment: hi Sreenivasulu , I have checked the dom structure in that i can't see the value 129.60 but i have to get that value in console to compare with excel using data-driven, through value only i have to compare is there any approach to compare the value

Comment: Hi Phani, I got your scenario. There are only two ways to get value from Ui either by getText() or by getAttribute(). But in your case, these two methods won't return any value as the value you are expecting is not a text and also, it's not assigned to aylny attribute. Hence, you can ask your Dev team to add the expected value as text to the same element or to pass same value with attribute. I dont think so, we have another way